# PHP cookie на локальном сервере и на хостинге

Tags: php, cookie

Всем привет. Столкнулся с банальной проблемой, которая действительно превратилась в проблему с печеньем. Юзал Code-igniter. После того как потестил на локальном компьютере сайт, убедившись сперва, что все ОК, загрузил в интернет, на хостинг.

Первое что вылезло в Code-igniter это то, что защита от csrf не работает, не отправляются формы. После несколько дневной "копки" в сайте, обнаружил, что в главном файле в /system/core/security.php в функции csrf_set_cookie() не получается записать данные в куки, хотя тот же сайт на локалке отлично работает.

Написал по файлу на лок. сервере и хосте:

```
setcookie('test','privet',time()+3600,'/');

 echo $_COOKIE['test'];
```

Как не странно, на лок. сервере работает, а на хосте нет.

Из за чего может не писать в куки ИМЕННО НА ХОСТЕ???

Первое что пришло в голову, может быть из-за того, что на сервере от корня сайта идет папка public_html.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотри в логе. Может там что будет по этому поводу.
Зачем писать  '/'   можно просто опустить это т.к и то и то создает куку для основного домена. Попробуйте опустить, может заработает.
Попробуйте вывести куки так.

```
echo $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["TestCookie"];

// Another way to debug/test is to view all cookies
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Еще вот пришло в голову, не знаю возможно ли...  time() дает время сервера + 3600 это час. Но если у вас с сервером разница во времени, то например на сервере 13:00 +3600  14:00  а у вас уже 15:00 браузер убьет куку.

и вот так вот сделайте

```
if (SetCookie("Test","Value")) echo "<h3>Cookies успешно установлены!</h3>";
```

Проверьте, ставит ли вообще сервер куку

Comment: С выводом все в порядке. Если работать с firebug, то на лок. сервере видно как добавляется новая кука, а на хосте она просто на просто не добавляется. И путь '/' так же не играет в моем случае роли. Без него или с ним, в равно кука не лезет.

Comment: Опа! Реально время сыграла роль. =) Благодарю за помощь. =)